# Sql Query to replace column value of real type into varchar type based on some condition

Tags: sql-server, database, replace

I have two tables from same database and one table from another database.The table from second database is `DCCT` from it, I want to retrieve two columns

**`logtime`**
and **`beam_current`**

The tables from another database is **`main_vacuum_analog`** and **`main_vacuum_status`**.On these two table I want to **apply following conditions**

**1)**`If` the **`value of columns st1_vs1_bag1_onoff,st1_vs1_bag2_rb_onoff,st1_vs1_bag3_rb_onoff is 0`** **in main_vacuum_status** table

**`THEN`**

The value of **`st1_vs1_bag1_rb,st1_vs1_bag2_rb,st1_vs1_bag3_rb in main_vacuum_analog is set to OFF`**

**`ELSE`**

The value of **`st1_vs1_bag1_rb,st1_vs1_bag2_rb,st1_vs1_bag3_rb in main_vacuum_analog reamins as it is`**

**2)** When ever **`DCCT.logtime == main_vacuum_analog.logtime`** ,then the **`beam_current and logtime`** from DCCT table should also be **`retrieved`**

how to do that.I **used case statement but it won't worked**.Moreover the **`values in all  **`st1_vs1_bag1_rb_onoff`** is of type real and OFF is varchar`**.How to fix it.

**EDIT 1**

What I tried with case statement is like that

```
select  
    case 
        when a.st1_vs1_bag3_onoff='1' and a.logtime=b.logtime 
            then 'OFF' 
        else 
            c.st1_vs1_bag3_rb 
        end
from 
    main_vacuum_status a, 
    INDUS2_BDS.DBO.DCCT b,
    main_vacuum_analog c
```

But it always give the values of st1_vs1_bag3_rb even when st1_vs1_bag3_onoff=1 .So **I didn't get expected output**.Moreover st1_vs1_bag3_rb is of type real ,how can I convert into OFF which is of varchar type whenever  st1_vs1_bag3_onoff=1??Moreover when I change b.logtime  to c.logtime then following error message comes **

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to real.
```

**

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected result?

Comment: Can you elaborate on ".I used case statement but it won't worked" did you get an error? or did you not get the expected result?